# Col 2:15 - Was the triumph over them "in him" or "in it"

Tags: grammar, paul, christology, colossians, cross

Within *what/who* were the rulers and authorities triumphed over?

Here is an example of the two version showing different options:

> **English Standard Version**
> He disarmed the rulers and authorities and put them to open shame, by triumphing over them ***in him.***

> **New King James Version**
> Having disarmed principalities and powers, He made a public spectacle of them, triumphing over them ***in it.***

Which is to be prefered **in him** or **in it**?

This question was inspired by this other question:
[When did Jesus disarm rulers and authorities?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/80529/25589)

If *"in it,"* then there should be no question that the rulers were disarmed at the cross. If *"in him"* then it's perhaps a little more amiguous

Comment: [Biblehub Interlinear](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/colossians/2-15.htm) shows that αὐτῷ is personal pronoun - dative, masculine 3rd person singular. So . . .  'him'. Yet the interlinear then follows some sort of tradition and gives the translation as 'it' ! ? ! Up-voted +1.

Comment: @Nijel, good point. Nearly all the literal translations on Biblehub.com prefer "it."

Answer (score 4):

The final Greek word in Col 2:15 is αὐτῷ, which as any Greek Grammar will show, is the dative singular case of both "it" (neuter) and "him" (masculine).

That is, grammatically, the last word of Col 2:15 could be legitimately translated as either "it" or "him".  The literal versions of the Bible are divided as to how they translate it, specifically:

- "it" as per BLB, KJV, NKJV, ASV, LSV, NAB, NRSV, NHEB, WEB, YLT, etc.  [Further, several versions have "the cross" thus supplying the antecedent for "it", namely, NIV, NLT, BSB, ISV, NET, etc.]
- "him" as per ESV, NASB, CSB, HCSB.

[I observe that many interlinear translations also have "it" such as https://biblehub.com/interlinear/colossians/2-15.htm ]

Therefore, if the translation choice cannot be decided on purely syntactical grounds, it must be decided on semantic grounds.  For the following reasons, I prefer the translation "it" (and its antecedent, "the cross") for the following reasons:

- the subject in view is "the cross" and its effect on Christian motivation as per Col 2:14
- the "public spectacle" can be none other than the ultimate Roman torture, the cross.
- the antecedent of "the cross" is grammatically closer than either "Jesus" or "Christ", thus making it more probable.

Meyer correctly observes:

> The reference to Christ is erroneous, because Christ is not mentioned
> at all in Colossians 2:14, and God pervades as subject the entire
> discourse from Colossians 2:11 onwards. We must hold, therefore, by
> the reference to τῷ σταυρῷ, so that ἐν αὐτῷ once more places the cross
> significantly before our eyes, just as it stood emphatically at the
> close of the previous sentence. At the cross God celebrated His
> triumph, inasmuch as through the death of Christ on the cross
> obliterating and removing out of the way the debt-bill of the law He
> completed the work of redemption, by which the devil and his powers
> were deprived of their strength, which rested on the law and its
> debt-bond.

Answer (score 4):

Verses 13 to 15 of Colossians 2 follow on from, and are the crescendo to, the previous verses :

> ... **in him** dwelleth all the fulness of the Godhead bodily. And ye are complete **in him** ...

That is to say, in Christ dwells all the fulness of the deity, bodily, and in Christ are the 'saints and faithful brethren' complete.

And :

> ... **in whom** also ye are circumcised ... buried **with him** in baptism.

The passage is all about being **in Christ.**

'And you'.... , begins Paul's description of an overwhelming release from the handwriting that was, previously, against his readers and in absolute condemnation of his readers, but now is nailed to the cross (it is not 'his' cross and 'he' did not do the nailing - it was God, in context, who nailed to **the** cross).

Having nailed the handwriting to the cross, God triumphed.

And God triumphed, not in wood, but in his own beloved Son.

The personal pronoun is clearly, in context . . . . **him**.

Answer (score 2):

There can be no effectual 'it' without the 'him' who died upon it, therefore I think the ambiguity is deliberate and both Nigel's and Dottard's answers are correct in combination.  The circumcision of humanity's sinful flesh happened in 'him' on 'it'.